# Phase diagrams and critical pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, temperature, states-of-matter

If a solid substance is pressurized past its critical pressure, what happens? Is the critical pressure only a factor when a substance is over the critical temperature also?

On another note what makes critical fluids special, and what is the distinguishability between critical fluids and super-critical fluids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the [definitions](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/?title=Textbook_Maps/General_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map:_Chemistry_%28Averill_%26_Eldredge%29/11:_Liquids/11.6:_Critical_Temperature_and_Pressure).

The *critical temperature* is the temperature above which no amount of pressure will cause a gas to liquefy.

The *critical pressure* is the pressure which will cause a gas to liquefy at its critical temperature.

A *supercritical fluid* is another state of matter. A liquid and a gas phase have been subjected to pressure such that the two phases disappear and only one phase remains.

I don't think *critical fluid* has any real definition other than perhaps a liquid-gas mixture at the critical point (critical temperature and critical pressure). I think this point would be more theoretical than real. You'd be trying to balance the system on a razor's edge.